# iframe won't absolute position

Tags: html, css, iframe

is it possible to absolutely position an iframe? I can position the top and left, but not the bottom and right. I need to do all 4 sides.

#### HTML

```
<iframe src="http://apple.com/" id="myframe"></iframe>
```

#### CSS

```
#myframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
}
```

check out my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bTrfD/)

Comment: Actually it's apply for 4 side include top, left, right, bottom and on absolute why bottom and right?

Comment: because I need to have a fluid frame height and width and not predefined using pixels

Comment: fluid? set the width:100%;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's just an Idea, I wrapped my `<iframe>` with a `<div>`, look here:
[jsfiddle.net/bTrfD/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/bTrfD/1/)

```
<div>
  <iframe src="http://apple.com/" id="myframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I used this technique. But I would recommend to either create a class to pass styling to similar iframes, or create an id for it. I have a page that has a lot of embedded videos that need to be positioned, so I created a class for the divs that wrap them.

Answer (score 2):

Its kind of a hack and its untested but try

```
#myframe {
  position:absolute;
  top:40px;
  left:40px;
  width:100%;
}
```

then add **"padding-bottom: 40px; padding-right: 40px"** on the parent element

EDIT

CSS tested

```
div{
    padding:40px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}
iframe{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

html

```
<div><iframe></iframe></div>
```

Comment: I dont have a parent element, the parent is `body`

Comment: never mind, I got it to work by positioning a parent div and doing `width:100%` on the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Lets do it with the css styles

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/krish/bTrfD/2/

```
    width:270px;
    height:150px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-75px 0 0 -135px;
```